# Python 2.7 - How to prevent assertion from releasing locks

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, assertion

When my program hits an assertion failure, I don't want the assertion library to do things that cause the program to progress further than it would have without the assertion failure. But that is exactly what the built-in `assert` seems to do: It raises an exception, which releases locks.

For example, consider the following program.

```
import threading
import time

lock = threading.Lock()

class Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        with lock:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print "ASSERTION ON NEXT LINE"
            assert False

            # Were it not for the assert, 
            # This thread would hold the lock for a while longer.
            time.sleep(1.0)
Thread()        


time.sleep(0.1)
with lock:
    print "*** Main Thread ***"
```

The assertion causes the lock to be released, which causes the main thread to acquire the lock in between the assertion failure and the traceback. As a result, the output is:

```
ASSERTION ON NEXT LINE
*** Main Thread ***
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "so.py", line 14, in run
    assert False
AssertionError
```

which is very undesirable because `*** Main Thread ***` is printed before the traceback. This can easily mislead one into thinking that the `*** Main Thread ***` acquired the lock before the exception was generated.

I know we could write our own assertion function that calls `os._exit()` instead of raising an assertion. What I'm wondering is if there is something like that already in the standard packages.

Comment: It's not assert but the context manager `with` statement which will automatically release the lock.

Comment: You have to distinguish between generation of exception and output of the stacktrace. The stacktrace is printed in the thread, but the main program continues to run.

Comment: Does it just go outside of the lock block?

Comment: @Daniel. Yes, that it was happens -- because `assert` is releasing the lock. The point of holding a lock is supposed to be to _stop_ other threads from running.

Comment: @Nikhil that is correct. But my point about `os._exit()` is that we know that we can prevent the `with` statement from doing that. In fact, you can call just about anything that doesn't throw an exception from within the `with` block, and it won't release your lock. `assert` is definitely something that we _don't_ want to release the lock. And yet, it seems it is one of the few things that does.

Comment: Exactly.  Assert raises an exception, and the context manager releases the lock when an uncaught exception causes it to go out of scope.  You need to either not generate an exception or not use a context manager.

Comment: @Evan. Yes the solution would have to involve either preventing the exception, or avoiding the context manager. The context manager is there for a good reason: to balance lock and unlock throughout the program. So, by process of elimination, we need to fix the assert to prevent the harmful exception. The question is just how to do that without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Evan. Well, hmm, maybe not exactly. I could almost have named the question "How to prevent assertion from raising exception", but I didn't want to preclude the remote chance that maybe there is some way to still generate the exception without releasing the lock. In fact, one could imagine doing that with a recursive lock, for example (It sounds kind of messy to do that. But so do many things in Python before we've seen the accepted patterns.)

Comment: @personal_cloud os._exit() is far more last thing that will happen in propogating uncaught exception (though I am not sure). With statement will release the lock pretty much early? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ explains how with is roughly equivalent to try/finally .... If you call os._exit() directly from with block thats different case and that's applicable to `try/finally` as well.

Comment: @Nikhil. Yes, the delayed `os._exit()` is exactly the problem in this case. `os._exit()` needs to be within the assert function -- rather than happening later after locks are released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your contributions. I am going to mostly build on Daniel's answer. I believe that the best answer depends on how much code is inside the lock. If you have a big function call, then

```
with lock:
    try:
        deep_complicated_function()
    except Exception:
        print "there was an exception"
        print '\n'.join(traceback.format_stack()[:-1])
        os._exit(1)
    while True:
        pass
```

is best because it gives you a chance to provide a handler for a large number of exception cases in one construct.

However, this is too much typing for one-off assertions like:

```
with lock:
   quick_update()
   assert property()
```

Those cases call for something more convenient, like:

```
def Assert(cond, msg = "Assertion failed."):
    if not cond:
        print msg
        print '\n'.join(traceback.format_stack()[:-1])
        os._exit(1)
```

This will stop the process, which simplifies debugging (as discussed in the question). To use in `nose` and other testing tools, launch your main program through a multiprocessing API and generate an exception when the exit code is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to release the `lock` you have to catch the exception inside the `with lock:`:

```
with lock:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print "ASSERTION ON NEXT LINE"
        assert False
    except Exception:
        print "there was an exception"
    while True:
        pass
```

Comment: That is of course equivalent to `if not (condition): print "assert failed"`. Which we could of course put into a function and call that "my_assert". I was looking for something that's already in a standard package.

Comment: seems, you have a X-Y-Problem. If so, the `if`-solution is the right way.

Comment: I am not sure what you're getting at. Have I not adequately identified the specific issue with `assert`? Or I haven't adequately illustrated why this is a serious problem in a multithreaded program? Every language has a usable `assert`, and we just need to discover how to import the prevailing one in Python.

Comment: The issue is most people don't consider this an issue with assert, but rather with your expectation.  You have two unsynchronized events: the printing of the stack trace in your thread's default exception handler and the print statement in main.  The order they happen is undefined.  BTW, you also have a race condition on starting the thread.  The correct thing to do is to not expect the default stack trace to be printed at a particular time relative to the main thread, and put any error handling you want inside the thread, holding whatever locks you want.

Comment: @Evan. That is not accurate. Most people expect two events to be synchronized when they occur within a lock block. Particularly when we know that neither of these events contains a `threading.Condition.wait()` or anything that could reasonably be releasing the lock.

Comment: And it is a reasonable expectation for an exception to release the lock when it causes program flow to leave the `with` block.

Comment: @BlackJack. Yes, that is reasonable. But in that case `assert` should not be raising an exception. Hitting `assert` failure means "the process's state is corrupted". (It doesn't mean somebody can catch the exception and keep running. If the state were salvagable then the more appropriate construct would be "return" or a specific documented exception like FileNotFound).

Comment: Well in Python it does actually mean somebody could catch the exception and keep running. You may not like it, but that's the way it is implemented and documented.  I don't think there will be any module or package with `assert` like functions, like unit test frameworks, that will not use raising an `AssertionError` as a way to signal a failed assertion.  On the contrary, as those frameworks rely on being able to handle that exception. You might have success filing a bug report how the library code calling `Thread.run()` deals with an `AssertionError` though.

Comment: @BlackJack can you elaborate that last idea bit? Are you suggesting perhaps that the thread library could be tweaked to somehow see that a thread has raised an `AssertionError`, and then prevent context switching until the traceback is printed? I think that would solve my problem.

Comment: I would suggest/propose that the thread library ends the program if it catches an uncaught `AssertionError`. After printing the traceback of course.

Comment: @BlackJack Well, it already prints the traceback and ends the thread in that case. The problem is it's context switching before printing the traceback, rather than first waiting to see whether the exception will be caught. And I'm not sure how such a wait would be implemented -- how long should the thread library wait to see whether an AssertionError is going to get caught? Or maybe it doesn't need to? Are the `try` blocks recorded in the stack somewhere?

Comment: [at]Daniel Actually I like your solution in half the cases. When there's a lot of stuff in the lock, yours is more flexible as it lets me choose additional actions before and/or instead of `os._exit()`. For smaller lock blocks, mine is more practical because I don't have to repeat the `try .. except` for every doggone lock block. If you post an additional, new solution that breaks it into case analysis that way, I will accept. I am banned from suggesting edits, note.

Answer (score 0):

if we use assert and that fails its gonna raise an assertion error. Because asserts are designed to do this only ( break/stop the flow). I could think of synchronise this with Queue.

```
import time
import threading 
from Queue import Queue



q = Queue()
# code here
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # do stuff
        print "ASSERTION ON NEXT LINE" 
        q.put(True)
        # do other stuff

# code here
mt = MyThread()
mt.start()

try:
    assert q.get()
finally:
    mt.join()
```

Comment: I don't see how `q.put()` would prevent the releasing of a lock within `run()`. The `q.put()` appears to be non-blocking. Also if we remove the assertion call we need something else in its place to print the traceback.